# I am having trouble using or importing matplotlib. This is the first line of my code: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

These are the messages I'm receiving and I have no idea what any of them mean.

I have `python 2.7.12` and have imported `matplotlib`.

In the command prompt window, the last update I installed was **conda install matplotlib** which seemed to update some stuff (`conda-env-2.5.2` and `conda-4.1.12`), but unfortunately not the stuff I needed.

I have never used any of this before so please speak in layman's terms if possible.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\plotting2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 40, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 23, in <module>
    import matplotlib.dates as _  # <-registers a date unit converter
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 130, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 38, in <module>
    from calendar import monthrange, isleap
ImportError: cannot import name monthrange
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there may be a conflicting module named calendar. Are there any other packages (files) called "calendar" (`calendar.py`) in your python path? Try opening up a new python console and type `from calendar import monthrange`.

Comment: I got this error when I ran that one line in a new file

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/helping.py", line 1, in <module>
    from calendar import monthrange
ImportError: cannot import name monthrange